# how to fire an onload event with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having a div and I want to style that div on page load with Jquery. The popup works fine But how can I fire it when the page loads.

```
<div id="popup">
   //Some content 
</div>
```

Below is the Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div#popup').load(function() {
                           // Popup Content
}
}
```

I even tried a simple alert message but doesnt work.

Thanks

Comment: Is this using jQuery UI Modal Dialog?

Comment: yes it using the Jquery UI Modal.

Comment: Not specific to the question, but you shouldn't use `$('div#popup')` to select elements by ID.  Use `$('#popup')` instead, it's more efficient. [Source](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to <kbd>style</kbd> it do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('div#popup').css({
           width: '100px',
           height: '100px' //etcetera
     });
});
```

Comment: If like me, you wonder what is used to give that look to `style` in the answer, it is wrapped in `<kbd></kbd>`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the outer wrapper:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //do something here
}
```

The `$(document).ready` closure doesn't execute until the entire DOM has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the jQuery UI Modal dialog then just make sure `autoOpen` isn't set to `false` in your dialog constructor. You'll notice that by default the `autoOpen` attribute is set to `true` so the standard behavior is to pop up the dialog automatically on page load. If this isn't happening, debug your page and be certain that your dialog constructor is being properly initialized on document ready.

Check out the "Options" tab on the [jQuery UI demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). The second option `autoOpen` contains documentation on the default behavior of the jQUI dialog's popup behavior.

The following code would be all it would take to do what you want to pop up a modal window. Remove the options parameter altogether if you need to to remove the modal behavior:

```
$(function() {
    $("div#popup").dialog({
         modal: true
    });
});
```